# Trouble calling C# Method from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I read some forums and found an easier way to call a `C#` Method from `JavaScript` but it's not working. I did it in my live app and it didn't work so I took a fresh project and used the code as below:

**ASPX Mark-up**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnMe" runat="server" OnClientClick="jsfun()" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function jdfun() {
            PageMethods.CSFun(onSucess, onError);

        }
        function onSucess(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
        function onSucess(result) {
            alert(result);
        }

    </script>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string CSFun()
    {
        string result = "Hey Yeah";
        return result;
    }
}
```

**No Error No Exception**. The Debugger is not even going into the `C#` code.
Can anyone help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: Before considering other things, is that a typo that you named function as `jdfun` and called it as `jsfun` or is that actual code? If so, try correcting it.

Comment: Yes i would like to reiterate @Mathew'c comment that did you check if your javascript code is running? Because you have called jsfun() onclientclick and in javascript you have written jdfun() function. This can be a probable reason.

Comment: Yes I did.. Was really silly, didnot worked

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I didn't really know about this, but I read a little and fixed your code.
Here is the code that works:

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jsfun() {
        PageMethods.CSFun(onSuccess, onError);
    }
    function onSuccess(result) {
        alert(result);
    }

    function onError(result) {
        alert(result);
    }
</script>
```

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
         <div>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="jsfun()" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would you like to go through http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/quickstart/ajax-tutorial-page-methods-in-asp-net/ here it says it is possible.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about that method. I read a little and fixed your code. BTW, using that doesn't look like a good practice to me. You either use a ajax or a form post to do stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Example to do the same

aspx page

```
<form runat="server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"
       EnablePageMethods="true" />
   <fieldset id="ContactFieldset">
       <label>
           Your Name
           <input type="text" id="NameTextBox" /></label>
       <label>
           Email Address
           <input type="text" id="EmailTextBox" /></label>
       <label>
           Your Message
           <textarea id="MessageTextBox"></textarea></label>
       <button onclick="SendForm();">
           Send</button>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Page Method (.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class ContactUs : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   [WebMethod]
   public static void SendForm(string name, string email, string message)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
       {
           throw new Exception("You must supply a name.");
       }

       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
       {
           throw new Exception("You must supply an email address.");
       }

       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
       {
           throw new Exception("Please provide a message to send.");
       }

       // If we get this far we know that they entered enough data, so
       // here is where you would send the email or whatever you wanted
       // to do :)
   }
}
```

**javascript function**

```
function SendForm() {
   var name = $get("NameTextBox").value;
   var email = $get("EmailTextBox").value;
   var message = $get("MessageTextBox").value;

   PageMethods.SendForm(name, email, message,
       OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
}

function OnSucceeded() {
   // Dispaly "thank you."
   $get("ContactFieldset").innerHTML = "<p>Thank you!</p>";
}

function OnFailed(error) {
   // Alert user to the error.
   alert(error.get_message());
}
```